# Windows service in C# + C++ is refusing to start in Docker

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, docker, managed-c++

I created a solution in VS 2017 with 2 main projects (& common ones). The architecture illustrates a very large legacy project, therefore cannot be changed.
The main project is a .Net executable which it's main class inherits from 'ServiceBase' class in order to be used as a Windows service. It defines WCF endpoint and uses an interface 'IWcfXmlServer' to process a request.
The other project is a C++ project with a class that implements 'IWcfXmlServer' interface and used to process a request.

I have created a Windows service locally and pointed it to the .exe file of the solution and it worked fine.

The next step is to put that app on a Docker container.
I added Docker support, which added "docker-compose" .yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  wcfservice:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}wcfservice
    build:
      context: .\..\WcfService
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

and a Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.1-windowsservercore-1709
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\app\\WcfService.exe"]
```

When I build the solution and start debugging I get:

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger.  A Windows Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Administrative tool or the NET START command.

but still, the container is created.

I opened PowerShell in the created Docker container and used "New-Service" to create a new service and point it to my .exe file. When I try to run Start-Service I get an error.

I used the Windows event log to get the error description:

> EntryType          : Error
>   Message            : Service cannot be started. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>                        assembly 'testole.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>                           at WcfService.WcfXmlServerFacade..ctor()
>                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>                           at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>                           at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>                           at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.CreateImplementation(Type serviceType)
>                           at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.SetupSingleton(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, Object implementation, Boolean isWellKnown)
>                           at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription.GetService(Type serviceType)
>                           at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implem...
>   Source             : WcfService1

- 'testole.dll' is my c++ project compiled.
  ** I already checked that 'testole.dll' is present in the same directory of the .exe file inside the container.

I can't figure out neither why it fails to run the C++ dll, nor how to get more information about the error (Console.Writeine() \ Debug.Writeine()) didn't work for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as the message says, testole.dll itself could reference other assemblies (and recursively) that are not available.

Comment: @SimonMourier - Great direction to inspect. I have : `#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>` in one of the files in the C++ dll. I'll try to figure it out and will update later.

Comment: those two should be here, they're core to the .net framework. look at the external libraries (.lib, .a) of the c++ project. Or you also can use the 'depends' tool http://www.dependencywalker.com/ directly on the .dlls or .exes

Comment: @SimonMourier . Thanks for your help. I still can't figure out what is the problem. I've tried the tool but it is not able to solve all dependencies and it's too messy. Is there a way I could get more information about the exception I get when I try to start the service in the Docker?

Comment: I know nothing about docker, but I guess there's probably some component that's usually there on every Windows, that is not on your docker environment.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yeah, probably...but I can't get a proper error I can work with. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you're missing Visual C++ Redistributable package. I suspect it's not installed by default on windows docker images.

Try adding following lines (for downloading VC++ 2015 Update 3 x64) to your Dockerfile just below `FROM` line:

```
ADD https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe /vc_redist.x64.exe
RUN C:\vc_redist.x64.exe /quiet /install
```

Source (https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/15)